# Java Date Formatting with java.text.SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have some code coming from the a ColdFusion 9 app that is java.
I would like the date to format like this Nov 05, 2012 no time.
currently it is formatting like this. 2012-11-05 00:00:00.0

Here is the code

```
    formatter = CreateObject("java", "java.text.SimpleDateFormat");
    formatter.init("EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss 'GMT'Z yyyy");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
formatter.init("MMM d , yyyy");


SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d , yyyy");
String s = format.format(new Date());  printed  **Apr 16 , 2013**
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `formatter.init("MMM d, yyyy")  ?`

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

I find it helps to write little programs with a main() method to experiment with the formats.